# Attaching method to Class event

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a web application which contains 50 pages & now i want to call a method on each page_load.So,Is there any way i can attach my method to existing class Event. So whenever that event gets raised my method will be called.

example : Can i attach mymethd() to page_load event of page class so whenever any page will load my mymethod() will be called. I dont want to inherit the page class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you build your website with "Master" pages? and derived each of your pages from the master?  That would definitely make it easier...

Then, add the method to the outer "Master" page and during ITs load event, auto instantiate the call to your "event".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use inheritance (by the way: why?) and you don't have a master page, an alternative I can suggest is using a [custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
It will not attach to the page_load but it will allow you to call your method on every request to a page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your objection is to using inheritance - it would just involve doing a Find/Replace.

E.g. if all your pages inherit from a common base page class.

```
public class TuscanoBasePage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        Response.Write ("<h1>This is a base page method</h1>");
    }
}
```

Then you inherit from this base page in your actual pages:

```
public partial class Default : TuscanoBasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.Page_Load(sender, e);

        Response.Write("<h2>This is coming from the page that inherits from TuscanoBasePage!</h2>");

    }
}
```